# Double tap to make change on checkbox Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have this checkbox inside the label

```
 <label for="test">
  <input id="test" type="checkbox" className="toggle-input"/>
 </label>
```

It works fine everywhere, but mobile safari.
When I try to tap on it in Safari, it first registers hover state. So I have to double tap it, to make the change. And I can't find the right solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to fix this I added css to label

```
label{
  &>*{pointer-events:none;}
}
```

Comment: Phpstorm shows me that this css syntaxis is incorrect. Could you correct the mistake? Thanks